# How to display Android images for multiples screens with assets folder

Tags: java, android

I have an assets folder with 10 folder inside and each folder has a set of images.  Ex folder1,folder2,.....folder10.
All my code is doing is generating  a random number and displaying the images correctly according to the folder selected from the random number generated.  The problem is that it looks different on various android devices is there a certain dimensions size because my image size is 300X300 and another 100X100 and I want it to work on all devices without the images looking to small for tablets or to big for regular phones

Comment: did you even attempt to research the topic http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 1):

First read what [Android Developer's Website](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) has said

Now in order to have your UI support multiple screens you should have different type of supporting **drawables**(xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldi) in your **res** folder i.e. containing same image with different resolution and density in all folders.

Also you can use **9 patch bitmaps** if you don't want to use different images in drawable folders, 9 patch image is re-sizeable bitmap that neither stretch nor shrink in case resolution of device is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to support all the screen sizes. You can see it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size like nexus-7
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen sizes like tablet
```

Also add this to your manifest

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

You can also use [this](http://anidea.com/technology/designer%E2%80%99s-guide-to-supporting-multiple-android-device-screens/) to guide you. Hope it helps.